# discord.js v13 filtering bots and calling regions

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

since discord.js v13 got officially released, I've been updating all my commands to v13 and I've been checking the docs the whole day. While I updated some stuff, I can't manage to seperate the bots in the guild and also calling the region. The following code looks like this.

```js
const regions = {brazil: 'Brazil', EUROPE: 'Europe', hongkong: 'Hong Kong', india: 'India', japan: 'Japan', russia: 'Russia', singapore: 'Singapore', southafrica: 'South Africa', sydeny: 'Sydeny', 'us-central': 'US Central','us-east': 'US Eastside','us-west': 'US Westside','us-south': 'US Southside'};
module.exports = {
    name: 'serverinfo',
    aliases: ['server'],
    execute: async (client, message, args) => 
message.channel.send({ embeds: [new MessageEmbed()
.setDescription(`Bots: {message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.user.bot).size}
Region:${regions[message.guild.region] || '❌'}`)] })
```

I had checked the docs several times and I still didn't find anything that could help me.

Oh Im sorry, I forgot. I cant call the amount of bots the guild has, it either crashes or just returns an [object Promise]. The second problem is, the region of the guild isnt displayed, it just returns ❌ instead of the actual voiceregion.

The code shown above works for v12 discord but not for v13.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a bit more clarity about what the issue is with the code you've provided? It's not clear what exactly you need help with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake here

```js
setDescription(`Bots: {message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.user.bot).size}
Region:${regions[message.guild.region] || '❌'}`)
```

You forgot the `$` for string concatenation.

Change it to this:

```js
setDescription(`Bots: ${message.guild.members.cache.filter(m => m.user.bot).size}
Region:${regions[message.guild.region] || '❌'}`)
```

If it worked for v12, you might have deleted the `$` sign by accident when you updated.